# GCP machines with 1:2 ratio of cpu/ram

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was wondering if there are any machines on GCP that have 2x more ram than cpu ? I checked provided list by them but not seeing anything like in the ratio of `4vcpu 8gb ram`, the available `2vcpu 8gb ram` or `8vcpu 8gb ram` is just a waste of resource for me atm https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no such pre-defined instance types, but you can easily create a Custom machine type with the desired amount of RAM and number of CPUs.

Just pick up a `Custom` machine type while creating the instance and configure it as needed.

Here is an example of such a configuration in the Google Cloud Console web UI:

[image]

Also, please consider checking the respective [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/creating-instance-with-custom-machine-type#specifications) to better understand the capabilities and restrictions of the custom machine types.